# How can I remove specific duplicates from a multimap?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, c++11, data-structures

I have a multimap with duplicates (duplicate keys) from which I like to delete every duplicate except for the one that was **recently added** to the multimap.

Let's say I have

```
multimap<int, int> multi;
multi.insert(pair<int, int>(1, 1));
multi.insert(pair<int, int>(1, 12));
multi.insert(pair<int, int>(2, 500));
multi.insert(pair<int, int>(2, 789));
multi.insert(pair<int, int>(1, 888));
```

I have iterated over this map and it looks like this:

```
1 : 1
1 : 12
1 : 888
2 : 500
2 : 789
```

Now I like to have the duplicates removed `1 : 1` and `1 : 12` because the last added pair was `1 : 888`. Also remove `2 : 500` because `2 : 789` was most recently added to the map.

But how can I do this? I have tried to put each element of this multimap into a normal map because it's removing duplicates by itself. The problem is that it doesn't keep the most recently added duplicate :c

Comment: Why don't you use `std::map` instead and then add values with `operator[]`?

Comment: Have you looked into [`equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range)? It'll return the range of elements with the same key. You should then remove all but the last one.

Comment: I bet that copying a multimap into a map will keep the first of each element, if it uses inserts. But I'm not sure if this is guaranteed. But if it's the case, copying using a reverse iterator would probably only keep the newest elements. Edit : In case of duplicate keys, which element is used is unspecified. There is a proposition to fix this : https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2844

Comment: Are you trying to get a new containers with only unique keys or are you trying to transform the `multi` in-place to have unique keys?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm not sure which one of both is what I'm looking for. I have a multimap because I need duplicates, and once a duplicate is found it needs to be updated, so I keep the most recently added one and delete the old (duplicate/s). I hope this answers your question? :s

Comment: @eyesima It doesn't sound like you actually need duplicates. If I understand correctly, before inserting, you can first`find` to see if that key already exists, update any existing element and then replace it. You could then use `map` and not worry about duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std::map` instead because it is:

> ... a sorted associative container that contains key-value pairs with
>   **unique** keys.

[`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) won't work because it:

> ... inserts element(s) into the container, if the container doesn't
>   already contain an element with an equivalent key.

However, you can workaround this behavior by using `operator[]` instead because it doesn't perform check whether key already exists.

By doing the following only the last value will be kept in the map:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> my;
    my[1] = 1;
    my[1] = 12;
    my[2] = 500;
    my[2] = 789;
    my[1] = 888;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the `std::map` would look like:

```
1 888
2 789
```

**UPDATE**

If you are able to use C++17, you can make a use of [`std::map::insert_or_assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign) that does the same thing as `operator[]` prior C++17.

You can use it like:

```cpp
std::map<int, int> my;
my.insert_or_assign(1, 1);
my.insert_or_assign(1, 12);
my.insert_or_assign(2, 500);
my.insert_or_assign(2, 789);
my.insert_or_assign(1, 888);
```

and the result would be the same.

Comment: `insert` doesn't work, but there is `insert_or_assign` since C++17.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it for example the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::multimap<int, int> multi;
    multi.insert( { 1, 1 } );
    multi.insert( { 1, 12 } );
    multi.insert( { 2, 500 } );
    multi.insert( { 2, 789 });
    multi.insert( { 1, 888 } );

    for ( const auto &item : multi )
    {
        std::cout << "{ "  << item.first << ", " << item.second << " } ";
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    if ( !multi.empty() )
    {
        for ( auto prev = std::begin( multi ), 
                   next = std::begin( multi ),  
                   last = std::end( multi );  
              ++next != last; )
        {
            if ( next->first == prev->first ) prev = multi.erase( prev );
            else ( ++prev );
        }             
    }

    for ( const auto &item : multi )
    {
        std::cout << "{ "  << item.first << ", " << item.second << " } ";
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
{ 1, 1 } { 1, 12 } { 1, 888 } { 2, 500 } { 2, 789 } 
{ 1, 888 } { 2, 789 }
```

If you want to create a copy with unique keys then you can use the standard algorithm `std::unique_copy`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::multimap<int, int> multi;
    multi.insert( { 1, 1 } );
    multi.insert( { 1, 12 } );
    multi.insert( { 2, 500 } );
    multi.insert( { 2, 789 });
    multi.insert( { 1, 888 } );

    for ( const auto &item : multi )
    {
        std::cout << "{ "  << item.first << ", " << item.second << " } ";
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
    std::multimap<int, int> multi2;

    std::unique_copy( std::rbegin( multi ), std::rend( multi ),
                      std::inserter( multi2, std::end( multi2 ) ),
                      []( const auto &a, const auto &b ) 
                      { 
                         return a.first == b.first ; 
                      } );

    for ( const auto &item : multi2 )
    {
        std::cout << "{ "  << item.first << ", " << item.second << " } ";
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
{ 1, 1 } { 1, 12 } { 1, 888 } { 2, 500 } { 2, 789 } 
{ 1, 888 } { 2, 789 }
```

Comment: oops my mistake. that `++next` increases iterator,so it will be ok.